# in MVC5 why does the SigninManager require a complex property in the User to have an empty constructor?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, asp.net-mvc-5

I am programming in C#, MVC 5, EntityFramework 6.

I have updated the User class with a complex Address class which has a constructor with a single parameter which I use to Encrypt/Decrypt the string fields. Everything works. However, when I tried to login through the AccountController, SigninManager, I got an error that no empty constructor was found for my Complex Class in the User. I solved the problem by providing an empty (no parameter) constructor for the complex class, which is a problem for me because I need a parameterized constructor. But who can argue with MVC5, and once again every thing works fine, but with a danger that I might initiate the Complex task with an empty constructor.

My Question is, in MVC5 why does the SigninManager require a complex property in the User to have an empty constructor?

Comment: i very much doubt this is actually a requirement from MVC and rather something you have introduced as a requirement through your modeling. Suggest that you check that. I.e. if user is use in your Sign in Class and Your "Complex class" is a property on user.. you you have introduced this, My suggestion is for sign-in stuff use a Lightweight User class to represent a user, and call the full detail when its actually needed.

Comment: Yes, Seabizkit, I have introduced it, but EF does allow us to customize the user. It was easier to bunch up the address string properties into a complex Address as opposed to single properties. Easier to handle, moreover, the documentation of Entity Framework states that it is our preference if we use properties or complex class containing simple types.. The cavet is, the complex class does not work exactly as simple fields, unless of course you have a simple constructor. I am planning to live with this, I was just wondering if anyone has some info on why, what, where.

Comment: EF allows you to do what ever you like within its own framework of what what you are doing is not the framework but rather your implementation. if you are implementing IPrinciple v2 or something like that and it doesn't work as expected then I suggest roll out your own. Again you are creating your own "problems", may I suggest that you post your code and explain how you think the framework is constraining you. PS all of what you are saying is a defect of your own implementation and not how it works. Its your implementation not the norm.

Comment: e.g why not just add a parameterless constructor . again its hard to actually see what you talking about with out code.....